# Use scanf to take hex instructions input from the user and save them in char. (C)

Tags: c, hex, scanf

So, I am building a program that should modify a specific number of bytes in a binary. You first input the binary, then the offset from which point you want the hex instructions to be replaced and then the bytes themselves.

Example:
I load example.exe
I specify offset `0` (beginning of the file)
I specify hex instructions: `4D FF 33 FD FE`
The first 5 instructions of the file should be replaced with the ones I provided. I use `fwrite` to do the modifications and `scanf` to get the offset and the hex instructions, however, I can't find a way to actually store them as hex. The fwrite actually writes `4D FF 33 FD FE` as text inside the binary file instead of hex. I assume I save them wrong in the `char` in the first place. I am new to C, so what I found online didn't really help.

Here's my code:

```
      scanf("%ld",&offset_ed);//get the offset from the user.
      fseek(f, offset_ed, SEEK_SET);
      printf("Specify HEX bytes to be written to the binary:  ");
      scanf("%s\n", &hexes);
      fwrite (hexes , sizeof(char), sizeof(hexes), f);
      fclose (f);
```

Where hexes is a char hexes;

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a _line_ of user input, then parse it for with `strtol()` or `sscanf(  ,"%x %n", )` for "hex bytes".

Comment: You need to open the file with `"wb"` and be careful, you don't magically replace the bytes. Probably you have to copy the file to another file and rename it.

Comment: I know I need to open the file properly, but I am actually using r+, is it bad? Also, The problem is that the user input isn't treated as HEX but as plain text.

Comment: @chux mind giving a small example? I am quite new to this.

Comment: You are reading as text with %s. You need to convert that to binary.

Comment: I know, I tried %x but it won't do. And fgets needs a length to be specified, which I don't know. The user may input 4F FF 90 or even FF FF 90 90 90 etc. I have variable input size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the hexes as a string so you need to convert each of them to unsigned chars(a byte) before you can write them to a file.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define ishexchar(c) (c>='A' && c<='F') || (c>='a' && c<='f')
#define toupper(c) c - 32
#define isupper(c) c>='A' && c<='F'

unsigned char hexconv(const char* str, int size){
    unsigned char ret = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(ishexchar(str[i])){
            char c = (isupper(str[i])) ? str[i] : toupper(str[i]);
            ret = (ret*16) + (c - 'A') + 10;
        }else{
            ret = (ret*16) + (str[i] - '0');
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    printf("%x\n",hexconv("4b", 2));
}
```

The code above might need some modification for your needs but it compiles and works.

Comment: Mind giving an example?

Comment: `isupper()` and `toupper()` are both standard C library functions.   Better to use a different name here to avoid that conflict and code-misunderstanding.

Comment: Using `#define ishexchar(c) ((c)>='A' && (c)<='F') || ((c)>='a' && (c)<='f')` would be more clear.  It works in ASCII and even [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)

Comment: Thanks. I'll fix it.

Comment: Concerning   `#define toupper(c) c - 32`, better to add `()` to insure desire evaluation - `#define toupper(c) ((c) - 32)`.  Of course, makes no difference with OP's code, yet is good practice.

Answer (score 3):

General idea below.

Do not use `scanf()`,  Use `fgets()` for reading a *line* of user input.

Error checking omitted (noted with // **)

```
 char buf[100];   // Use some reasonable upper bound of expected user input.

 puts("prompt for input");
 fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);     // **
 offset_ed = strtol(buf, NULL, 10); // **
 fseek(f, offset_ed, SEEK_SET);     // **

 puts("prompt for input");
 fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);  // **
 size_t byte_count = 0;
 unsigned char hexes[(sizeof buf)/2] = 0;  // place to save the "hex bytes"
 int n = 0;
 unsigned byte;
```

Now parse the string looking for hex input.

```
 // Use "%n" to save the offset of the scan to later update `p`
 // Robust code would use `strtol()` for its better error handling
 char *p = buf;
 while (sscanf(p, "%x %n", &byte, &n) == 1) {
   if (byte > 0xFF) Handle_OutOfRange();
   hexes[byte_count] = byte;
   p += n;  
 }  

 if (byte_count == 0) Handle_EmptyUserInput();
 if (*p) Handle_ExtraJunkInUserInput();
 fwrite (hexes , byte_count, sizeof hexes[0], f); // **
```

---

OP had `scanf("%s\n",...`.  The `"\n"` is a problem. `scanf()` will block until  the user entered some non-white-space after the expected input.  Avoid that.

The problem *can* be handled with `scanf()`, yet it is ugly.  Effectively, code needs to look for the `'\n'` somewhere after multiple "hex" bytes using `scanf("%*1[^\n]")` or the like.  `scanf()` is not the best tool for the overall coding goal here.  `scanf()` is rarely the sharpest tool in the shed.

Comment: This gives out: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal for the unsigned char hexes[(sizeof buf)/2] = 0; and error: use of undeclared identifier 'end' for the "while (sscanf(p, "%x %n", &byte, &end) == 1)"